# cleaning django db of previous tables

Tags: django, postgresql, django-users

I had a table in Postgres called user that was a custom model. I then switched over to the default Django User class, but there have been issues because of the name overlap. How can I either wipe the previous table, or wipe the entire DB (still in testing, so not a big deal) to start over?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to execute a `DROP TABLE` statement directly in your database prompt, remember that Django models are just like any other table for your database

Answer (score 0):

dropdb --help

Run this in the terminal